# Different template fallback when changing permalinks

Tags: permalinks, slug, template-hierarchy

I am creating my own WP theme from scratch. Super basic stuff. But something drives me nuts.

First of all, took me long time to realize that the page with all the posts is home.php. I thought it would be archive.php as a default..

Anyway. My posts page is the page where I want a complete overview of all available posts. I called my posts page Portfolio, with the slug also Portfolio.

Now, when the permalink structure is 'Plain' (default) and I view my Portfolio page i see the correct design that falls back to home.php. As is in line with the WP hierarchy right? Only the url of the page = website.com/?page_id=23. So it is an page ID and thats ugly. So I changed the permalink structure to custom %postname%. Then, the Posts Page (called Portfolio) shows the URL website.com/portfolio. But, then the design falls back to archive.php.. How can I have the right permalink structure AND let my posts page fall back to home.php like it should?

Please help me! I have a feeling I don't understand the WP Hierarchy structure just yet..

Best,
Arwin

Comment: look up the template hierarchy, WP will try to load specific templates then fallback to more generic templates until it finds something that exists. `home.php` should only appear on the homepage. There is special unique behaviour around which template is loaded if you pick a page in the settings area to show your posts on that bypasses the template hierarchy somewhat.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks.

Comment: @ddur thanks. I will look into this.